# Can I use pseudo classes inside jQuery .css() method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery code which works as just the class, but the `:hover` causes it not to work.

`$('.dd_question:hover').css('border','1px dashed #333333');`

Is there some special code I can use inside th `$()` method? Or is `:hover` simply not allowd?

Comment: simply not allowed. Well, it is allowed, but think about it and you'll probably realize why it doesn't work.

Comment: try `$('.dd_question').hover(function() { $(this).css('border','1px dashed #333333'); });`

Comment: Just curious, if you are just toggling the CSS, why not simply use CSS?

Comment: @Swordfish0321: The obvious answer is that he only sometimes wants hovering over the dd_question elements to toggle the border. If it is behavior that should always happen, then you are of course correct, and straight CSS is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery selector selects elements that match the selector **when the code is executed**, not when the user hovers over an element.

With that in mind, `$('.dd_question:hover')` will only select elements that have that class and that were currently being hovered over **when the code was executed** which most likely was 0 elements.

You need to either use the mouseenter and mouseleave events (or hover for short), or simply use css.

Answer (score 6):

Other people have already explained why the code you're using isn't working, but the other question is how to fix it. Probably the best way to get the effect you're looking for is to have

```
.hoverborder:hover {border: 1px dashed #333333;}
```

in your css, and then use

```
$('.dd_question').addClass('hoverborder');
```

in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for work arounds now since it's clear that simply `:hover` inside my jQuery method won't work, and this looks like it may do the trick.